# Unsupported Operand Type with ConfigParser

Tags: python, parsing, types, configparser

I am trying to make a game where the player is deducted .5 from a value in a ini file every time he plays. However I keep getting an error and I am not sure what to do. This is my code. Dont worry about the comments, those are for me, and I do close the while loop later. This is just a portion of the code. Btw, the code works, just not this. Thanks.

```
def rerun():
import ConfigParser
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('Game.ini')

PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount')
#config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
configFile = open("C:\Python27\Game.ini", "w")
#config.read(configFile)
#valueamount = config.getfloat("section","starting_value")
print PlrMny

print "You will be given a $10 starting amount. Each game costs $.50 to play and is 
deducted when you input the first value."
print "\nGetting one match gives $1 and the output is multiplied by 2 for each extra 
match."
print "\nCurrent Amount =",PlrMny,

def gamble():

    import random
    import sys
    number1 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number2 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number3 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number4 = random.randint (1, 20)
    number5 = random.randint (1, 20)



    def input():
        c = 0
        PlrMny == type(int)
        print "\n\n\n\nTry guess what five numbers the computer will guess. Type '100' 
        in any of the inputs to close program prematurely"    
        print "Money =",PlrMny,
        #parser.set("money_value", "Amount",10000)
        #parser.write ('Game.ini')

        while True:
            try:
                User11 = int(raw_input( "\n\nNumber 1 : "))
                parser.set('money_value','Amount',PlrMny - .5)
                parser.write (configFile)
                if User11 < 1:
                    print "Error"
                elif User11 == 100:
                    sys.exit()
                elif User11 > 20:
                    print "Error"
                else:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print "Error"
```

Here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 181, in <module>
    rerun()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 180, in rerun
    gamble()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 174, in gamble
    input()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 42, in input
    parser.set('money_value','Amount',PlrMny - .5)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Help?

Comment: in the future, be sure to mark python questions with the `python` tag. Those who follow the python tag will see python tagged questions first.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to subtract .5 from a string, not a float. That is, your variable PlrMny is a string.

Replace the line

```
parser.set('money_value','Amount',PlrMny - .5)
```

with

```
parser.set('money_value','Amount',str(float(PlrMny) - .5)) #if you want money_value to be a string
```

However, using `parser.set` will not change the value of the `PlrMny` within the running program. It will only change the value within the context of your .ini file. So, what you probably want to do is use this code:

```
PlrMny = float(PlrMny) - .5
parser.set('money_value','Amount',str(PlrMny))
```

You will need to cast PlrMny as a string when writing to the ini inorder to avoid errors when reading the ini file.

Comment: Alright, I can t believe I didnt do that before... thanks. However, when I do that the value stays at (8.5 in ini file but rounded for some reason, probably because it is float?) 9. Also, the ini file looks like: (after 3 uses)

Comment: [money_value]
amount = 8.5

[money_value]
amount = 8.5

[money_value]
amount = 8.5

Comment: It shouldnt be printing that 3 times, but rather editing the first one, and it should also be decreasing by .5. Help?

Comment: @user2238780, I think this is because you never close the file.  Since the file stays open while you are in your loop you are appending to the existing file.

Comment: Alright, you were correct. But now, when I run the program, it updates to the correct value, however, while running, its prints the same number i started with, but then updates when I close the program

Comment: So, that was because I was assigning PlrMny outside of the current function. However when I assigned it inside the function I get:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: @user2238780 See my latest update. Also consider keeping `PlrMny`a float throughout the entire program. So when you originally read PlrMny from the ini file, use float(`PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount'))` This will make your program a little cleaner.

Comment: @user2238780 Your "TypeError" is probably (I don't know the line you are getting your error on) a casting error. One of your variables is a string and the other is a float

Comment: FULL ERROR:

File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 183, in <module>
    rerun()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 182, in rerun
    gamble()
  File "C:\Python27\Gamb Game.py", line 19, in gamble
    PlrMny = parser.get('money_value', 'Amount')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 623, in get
    return self._interpolate(section, option, value, d)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 663, in _interpolate
    if value and "%(" in value:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Comment: @user2238780, I can't keep this discussion going in the comments.  This is a problem with parsing a float instead of parsing a string. You should work with your code some and then post a new question if you still have an error.